# How to query OData while using alternate property names

Tags: c#, odata

I am using Newtonsoft to change property names on the web api json output.

```
public class User : IEntity
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "user_name"]
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

I've enabled odata query so that i can add queries to the request.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/users")]
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<User> GetUser()
{
    return dbContext.DbSet<User>();
}
```

When i make a query using the alternate property name, it fails.

> GET /api/users?$select=user_name
>
> The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'user_name'

The query works fine if I use the entity model name, `Username` (which is not visible to public). How can i fix this while still using Newtonsoft to handle deserialization?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33663255/odata-entity-property-serialization-name-different-than-c-sharp-variable-name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've not been able to achive this with the Json.Property attribute but instead this way:

```
// in class WepApiConfig    
ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
var conf = builder.EntitySet<User>("users");
conf.EntityType.Property(f => f.Username).Name = "user_name";
```

the query

```
GET /api/users?$select=user_name
```

should work now (with my OData service it works fine)

My answer is based on the reply to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32349274/aliasing-renaming-properties-on-entities-in-odata) but with minor corrections.